# Keep getting the same random values when using a function

Tags: python, function, loops, random, integer

I want to make a program that will do some kind of battle logs. You strike with 50% chance of hitting the enemy and deal damage from 10 to 25.

```
from random import randint

hitChance = randint(0,1)
damage = 10 + randint(0, 15)
HP = 100

def atack():
    global HP

    if hitChance is 0:
        print("Missed")

    elif hitChance is 1:
        HP -= damage
        print(damage, " delt")
        print(HP, " left")

while HP > 0:
    atack()
    print("You defeated the enemy!")
```

However when i run this code it either stuck in an infinite loop of "missed" or deals the same damage values.

Comment: You don't ever re-define `damage` and `hitChance` and so it will always be the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your variables out of the global space and put them into the function.

```
HP = 100

def atack():
    global HP
    hitChance = randint(0,1)
    damage = 10 + randint(0, 15)

    if hitChance == 0:
        print("Missed")

    elif hitChance == 1:
        HP -= damage
        print("{} delt".format(damage))
        print("{} HP left".format(HP))
```

Then, get your final print call outside your while loop.

```
while HP > 0:
    atack()

print("You defeated the enemy!")
```

Sample output:

> ```
> 14 delt
> 86 HP left
> 14 delt
> 72 HP left
> 15 delt
> 57 HP left
> Missed
> Missed
> Missed
> Missed
> Missed
> 23 delt
> 34 HP left
> 10 delt
> 24 HP left
> 10 delt
> 14 HP left
> Missed
> Missed
> Missed
> Missed
> 15 delt
> -1 HP left
> You defeated the enemy!
> ```

Comment: @HermanLeshkovtsev, don't use is to compare values, "is" is used for identity checks not values.

Comment: For finer control, I'd use `random` instead of `randint`, e.g. `hitChance > 0.7` to require greater than 70 percent chance to hit or `hitChance > target.evadeChance` when using classes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need global and it is rarely a good design to use it at all,you can just pass and return the updated HP to and from the attack function:

```
HP = 100

def attack(HP):
    hitChance = randint(0,1)
    damage = 10 + randint(0, 15)
    if hitChance ==  0:
        print("Missed")
    elif hitChance == 1: # == not is 
        HP -= damage
        print(damage, " delt")
        print(HP, " left")
    return HP

while HP > 0:
    HP = attack(HP) # reassigns HP from current to HP minus an attack
print("You defeated the enemy!")
```

Comment: Upvote for suggesting a way to get rid of the global

Answer (score 1):

You generate two random numbers when the program is started, and never change them. What you should do instead is generate them afresh every time `attack()` is called:

```
HP = 100

def atack():
   hitChance = randint(0,1)
   damage = 10 + randint(0, 15)
   ...
```

Also, use `==` rather than `is` to compare integers (or, for that matter, most other things):

```
if hitChance == 0:
```

The `is` operator has its uses, but they are pretty rare.